# Showing $1 + 4\cos{2\theta} + 6 \cos{4\theta} +4\cos{6\theta}+ \cos {8\theta} =16\cos{4\theta} \cos^4 \theta$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, summation

> Show that $1 + 4\cos{2\theta} + 6 \cos{4\theta} +4\cos{6\theta}+ \cos {8\theta} = 16\cos{4\theta} \cos^4 \theta$

Do I solve this question by using summation of series?

Comment: In terms of [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html) $T_n(x)$, you want to prove $1 + 4T_2(x) + 6T_4(x) + T_8(x) = 16T_4(x)x^4$

Comment: Where do you get this equation? according with WA is not true

Comment: If $\theta=0$ then the left side is $12$ and the right side is $16$. Not sure how you can show something that is not true. Maybe you've copied the question wrong?

Comment: The correct equation is: 
$$1 + 4\cos{2\theta} + 6 \cos{4\theta} +4\cos{6\theta}+ \cos {8\theta} = 16\cos{4\theta} \cos^4 \theta$$

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, I didn't notice it was missing. So do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $cos(u)=\frac{e^{iu}+e^{-iu}}{2}$. It's just algebra after that.

Answer (score 1):

i am going to use $t$ for $\theta$

$\begin{align}
1 + 4\cos{2t} + 6 \cos{4t} +4\cos{6t}+ \cos {8t} &=
(1 + \cos 8t) + 4(\cos 2t + \cos 6t)  + 6 \cos 4t \\
&=2\cos^2 4t + 8\cos4t \cos 2t+6\cos 4t\\
&=2\cos 4t (\cos 4t + 4\cos 2t + 3)\\
&=4\cos 4t (\cos^2 2t + 2\cos 2t + 1)\\
&=4\cos 4t [(2\cos^2t -1)^2 + 4\cos^2t - 1]\\
& = 16\cos 4t\cos^4 t\\
\end{align}$

i used the formula $\cos 2A + \cos 2B = 2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B),$ called the sum to product formula for $\cos,$ many times. you can use this formula even in the case one of $A$ or $B$ equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

More generally the expression you look is this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \cos{2k\theta} $$

If you look at the expression of cosine in terms of the complex exponential:

$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Then replacing:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{e^{2ik\theta}+e^{-2ik\theta}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \left(e^{2i\theta}\right)^k + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \left(e^{-2i\theta}\right)^k $$

The binomial theorem states:

$$(1+r)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}r^k$$

Therefore using that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{e^{2ik\theta}+e^{-2ik\theta}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{2i\theta})^n+ \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}e^{2i\theta n}(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n+ \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2i\theta n}+1)(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n= \frac{1}{2}(e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})^n $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}2^{n+1}\cos n\theta \cos^n \theta=2^{n}\cos n\theta \cos^n \theta$$

Then when $n=4$ you would get your result.