# Binomial coefficients and cosin

Tags: trigonometry, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105380/showing-1-4-cos2-theta-6-cos4-theta-4-cos6-theta-cos-8-theta-1/1105574#1105574) the user ask to prove the next identity:

$$1 + 4\cos{2\theta} + 6 \cos{4\theta} +4\cos{6\theta}+ \cos {8\theta} =16\cos{4\theta} \cos^4 \theta$$

I realized the terms in the left side are expression of a more general term:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \cos{2k\theta} $$

(the expression of the OP is $n=4$).

Question there is a way to calculate that sum?

Obviously using the binomial theorem you can show:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{e^{2ik\theta}+e^{-2ik\theta}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{2i\theta})^n+ \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}e^{2i\theta n}(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n+ \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2i\theta n}+1)(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n$$

But how show an expression in terms of $\cos$?

Comment: $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ and plug it in, then just take the real part.

Comment: sorry just realized the *insane* mistake I made .. edited. Why don't you edit it in the other answer of yours? :)

Comment: @sciona thanks! I'll do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(e^{2i\theta n}+1)(1+e^{-2i\theta})^n = (e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta})(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})^n = 2^{n+1}\cos n\theta \cos^n \theta$$